# Gameshow countdown music

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a small html file which creates a timer image and plays a timer music when I click it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function playSound(soundfile) {
                document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = "<embed src=\"" + soundfile + "\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle">
                    <a href="#" onclick="playSound('timer.mp3');">
                        <img src="timer.png"/>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <span id="dummy"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am new to JavaScript but here is what I want:

> When the user click the image the music should be played non-stop until the user clicks the image again.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you use `<embed>`? Use `<audio>` instead

Comment: @Derek: I did not know about that tag.

Comment: [MDN `<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/audio) Use this tag to play audio file, and you can control it easily with JavaScript.

Comment: @MDN: Can you give me the changed code for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<audio id="player" controls="controls"></audio>     Remove "control" if you don't
<button onClick="playFile('timer.mp3')">Play/Stop</button>            need it.

var playing = false;                                    //pre set plaing to false
function playFile(n){
    var player = document.getElementById("player");     //get the <audio>
    player.src = n;                                     //set the url
    playing = !playing;                                 //flip the status
    playing ? player.play(): player.stop();             //play/stop
    player.addEventListener("ended", function(){        //When ended,
        player.play();                                  //play again
        //do other stuff
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <audio id="myAudio" controls preload loop>
  <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.mp4" type='audio/mp4'>
   <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga" type='audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis'>
    Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
   </audio>
     <img src="img/ex1.png" onclick="aud_play_pause()"/>
       <script>
        function aud_play_pause() {
      var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
      if (myAudio.paused) {
    myAudio.play();
       } else {
      myAudio.pause();
       }
  }
   </script>
```

use this code for non stop audio play on image button.
set your audio in source src.